# JDBC Connection String with selectMethod=cursor breaks connection

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, tomcat, jboss

I'm trying to deploy a `JBoss` webapp that requires `selectMethod=cursor` in the jdbc driver connection string.

But when I try connecting to my mssql (2008) database with this in the string, it just timesout when connecting. When I remove `selectMethod=cursor` from my connection string, it works/connects, but my app doesn't work and gives me this error: `[SQLServer JDBC Driver]Can't start a cloned connection while in manual transaction mode.`

I have already updated my `jdbc` driver - tested all versions.

Here is my connection string:

jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1434;DatabaseName=xxxx;user=xxxx;password=xxxxx;selectMethod=cursor

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from using a microsoft jdbc driver to jtds jdbc driver and it works wonderfully again.

Answer (score 0):

Do the [Microsoft docs on the issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313181) shed any light on this?

> This error occurs when you try to execute multiple statements against a SQL Server database with the JDBC driver while in manual transaction mode (AutoCommit=false) and while using the direct (SelectMethod=direct) mode. Direct mode is the default mode for the driver.

Resolution is:

> When you use manual transaction mode, you must set the SelectMethod property of the driver to Cursor, or make sure that you use only one active statement on each connection as specified in the "More Information" section of this article.